# React Native Xcode 13.2 Error no such file or directory for NativeVibration.js

Tags: react-native

After creating the project with react-native init, i found this issue in terminal as well as in xcode. After digging deep, i found that this particular file is showing missing in project node modules.

Here are example of error codes showing in xcode & terminal-

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,

/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/../../Libraries/Vibration/NativeVibration.js
```

Answer (score -1):

I've learned the hard way when programming in react native (for cross platform/hybrid application development), many unknown issues will be caused if you deviate from native OS clustering. Make sure you don't make the same mistakes as I have.

Answer (score -1):

I have more specific help for you, apart from the obi wan style in my previously semi-answer.

Another guy had an issue with this a few years back, he asked and was answered,"delete your node_modules and app from simulator. Then re-install everything back, clear cache and see if it start bundler from root directory.

Before doing that, you can try 'react-native start' from your root directory.

I have seen that error message a lot, specifically with jest. But that's a different fix. I realize you are not using jest to test your reactjs, but it is jest tests runner that is the problem that causes the same outcome as you have come to- solution there is to disable the jest runner from running in the background while installing new packages.
I wonder if there isn't a similar solution here - only applicable to xcode - although you see it in terminal, that's probably just the cmdline not recognizing the path to the directory or at least that file.
Should be easy to figure out with terminal--
Go to $HOME~ type dir or ls, to see your directory folders, if you see the project listed, cd into it or, just search for the directory apt-get search [package] or apt, pkg, pip, pacman, snap etc etc whatever your flavor if OS terminal is, or search for the file-- $find / -iname [query] or even search for all paths containing the phrase: $locate [query]... If you created it, it exists. Just because xcode can't find it, and initial attempts in term produced nada, don't believe it is not in your system. just a matter of where, what, and why a  process or dependancy is missing or malfunctioning in attempt to retrieve the file & open it.
You can definitely find it - i don't know jack about xcode, but terminal -- I can get anything from anywhere on cmdline-- you can too. I have to go, but I'm curious if you have figured it out. Let us know yeah? Best of luck to you. Cheers QwaziRidwanhasib.

-Cujo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).